# Adding X-Robot-Tag to response header in Sitecore 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitemap, sitecore8

I have got a website setup in Sitecore. My sitemap is an item in sitecore which is under the homepage.

I am able to access my sitemap by typing following URL:
   http://example.com/xmlsitemap
Whereas xmlsitemap is the name of the item in Sitecore. Which has the rendering to get the XML sitemap given below:

```
XmlDocument SiteMap = new XmlDocument();
SiteMap.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "//SiteMap//Sitemap-" + Sitecore.Context.Site.SiteInfo.Name + ".xml");
return this.Content(SiteMap.InnerXml, "text/xml");
```

I have got multiple site setup in sitecore. That's why I created sitemap as an Item in sitecore. So that it gets the right sitemap for each website.

The issue is when I submit this sitemap to google using the URL. It is indexing the sitemap URL as well and it is appearing in the actual results.

I know I can stop google from indexing my sitemap by adding X-Robot-Tag: noindex. But I can't do it IIS because it is not an item inside the website directory.

Any ideas on how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can specify the header in your `web.config` by specifying it within a [location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.85).aspx) node.

```xml
<configuration>
...
    <location path="xmlsitemap">
        <system.webServer>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="X-Robots-Tag" value="noindex" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

You can add this manually, the file does not need to be physically present in IIS.

Comment: When adding the location section in the web.config. I am getting the following error. 
'The configuration section 'location' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration' 
I think it might be because of the schema of the web.config is not defined for sitecore?

Comment: Ignore my last comment. Got it working wasn't putting the section in the right place. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it another way and use a pipeline processor to produce your sitemap. This way the site map will not be indexed by google as the site map will not be an item in Sitecore.

Here's some code I use that checks for sitemap.ashx in the url and renders out the url, priority etc in xml required for google sitemap. This will also pick up on the context site so you can use it for multiple sites.

```cs
 public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
 {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;

        string sRequestedURL = currentContext.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();
        if (!sRequestedURL.EndsWith("sitemap.ashx"))
            return;

        // uses get descendants which isn't very good for performance!! Might want to change this part
        Item[] items = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath).Axes.GetDescendants();
        if (items.Length > 0)
        {
            string priority = "1.0";     

            // class used to create xml nodes          
            SiteMapFeedGenerator feedGenerator = new SiteMapFeedGenerator(currentContext.Response.Output);
            feedGenerator.WriteStartDocument();

            foreach (Item node in items)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(node["Sitemap Display"]) && node["Sitemap Display"] == "1")
                {
                    feedGenerator.WriteItem("http://" +currentContext.Request.Url.Host  + LinkManager.GetItemUrl(node), DateTime.Now, priority);
                }
            }

            feedGenerator.WriteEndDocument();
            feedGenerator.Close();

            currentContext.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            currentContext.Response.Flush();
            currentContext.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

You can run this processor in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline.